# x86 Program Freeze [tasm]

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have this code ( `having a string of length n, build another of length n-2 as it follows: sir2[i]=(sir[i]+sir[i+1]+sir[1+2])/3` ) and I can't figure out why it is freezing. there are no errors and I've been debugging for a while now, but I can't figure out if the problem is with the algorithm.

```
prints macro number
local  decompose, pops
    mov bx,10
    mov al, number
    mov cx,0
    decompose:  ;pushing digits to the stack
        inc cx
        mov ah,0
        div bl
        mov dl,ah   ; remainder - last digit
        add dx,48   ; to transform it in its char version
        push dx
        cmp al,0
        jnz decompose
    pops:               ; pop digits off the stack
        pop dx
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h
    loop pops
        ; pretty spacing
        mov dl,' '
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

endm

data segment para public 'data'
    sir db 5, 10, 12, 4, 3
    n equ $-sir
    sir2 db n-2 dup(0)
data ends

code segment para public 'code'
start proc far
    assume cs:code,ds:data
    push ds
    xor ax,ax
    push ax
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    mov si,0
    mov dx,3
    mov cx,n
    sub cx,2

l1:
    mov ah,0
    mov al,sir[si]
    add al,sir[si+1]
    add al,sir[si+2]    ;sum of 3 numbers
    div dx                  ;sir2[i]=(sir[i]+sir[i+1]+sir[1+2])/3
    mov sir2[si],al
    inc  si
    cmp si,cx
jbe l1

    mov si,0
l2:
   prints sir2[si]
    inc si
loop l2

ret
start endp
code ends
end start
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What effort have you made to discover why it is freezing and where were you stuck? In other words, **did you debug your code**? This site is not a free debugging service and hence as your question stands, it will be, most likely, closed as off-topic.

Comment: Yes I did + I thought I was stuck in a loop so I changed it for a jmp.

Comment: You cleared CX within the *decompose* routine!!! Change `mov cx,0` into `mov ah,0`

Comment: I accidentally wrote **CX** instead of **AH**. Thanks.

Comment: You should not 'fix' a question to include the actual answer. It's great you've come to a solution, but the answers provided by others lose sense if you edit the question like you did.

Comment: I get it, sorry. But I was asked to update it so they can check my corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
div dx                  ;sir2[i]=(sir[i]+sir[i+1]+sir[1+2])/3
```

to

```
div dl                  ;sir2[i]=(sir[i]+sir[i+1]+sir[1+2])/3
```

(see Michael's answer).

A macro is a piece of code which is inserted "as is" at the place where the macro is called. The macro `prints` changes `CX` which you need untouched for `loop l2`. Rewrite the loop:

```
    mov si, 0
    mov di, cx
l2:
    prints sir2[si]
    inc si
    dec di
    jnz l2
```

BTW: Don't forget to define a stack:

```
_STACK SEGMENT PARA STACK 'STACK'
    dw  1024 dup (?)
_STACK ENDS
```

Comment: Is it allowed to write `cmp si,n-2` ?

Comment: @LorenaSfăt: Yes. TASM translates `n-2` at compiletime into a constant number.

Comment: Ok so now I figured it must be the algorithm since it prints some values (not the right ones) and then it freezes...

Comment: @LorenaSfăt: It works here. Maybe you should define a stack. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure it gives you the right answers? :D I'm going nuts

Comment: @LorenaSfăt: 5 10 12 4 3 => 9 8 6 as I expected. What did you expect?

Comment: I know that's the right answer. It's just that I get 1 7 2.

Comment: @LorenaSfăt: There's an error in your second version of the macro `Prints`. The first version works well.

Comment: Yes, as I said I accidentally wrote CX instead of AH. Thank you very much. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

The description for `DIV r/m16` is *"Unsigned divide `DX:AX` by `r/m16`"*. In other words, the numerator is the 32-bit value formed by the bits in `DX` and `AX` combined.
If the quotient becomes too large to fit in `AX` you get an exception. To avoid this you should clear `DX` prior to the division (i.e. `mov dx,0` or `xor dx,dx`). Obviously this also means that you can't use `DX` as the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Your program might freeze because you are doing an iteration too many!

```
cmp si,cx
jbe l1
```

This gives 4 iterations while *sir2* has only 3 bytes of storage! Use `jb l1`

Comment: I wish that was it. I did what all of you said and now it prints values (not the right ones) and then it freezes.

Comment: I you want this program to exit on a mere `ret` then you should remove the `push ds` and `push ax` instructions. Alternatively use `mov ah,4Ch` and `int 21h` as the last step of your program.

Comment: But the teacher said that's part of the body of a .exe program and we should take it as it is :/

Comment: You might want to post all the changes everyone suggested as an EDIT in your original question so we can verify if you did it correctly.